# error: users.find is not a function but acttualy it is

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, axios

i' m trying do create my **first** API for a project, using [NODE.JS](https://nodejs.org/en/), [express](https://expressjs.com/it/) and [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

When i try to use `node app.js` from the terminal (app.js is the server file) everything it's fine, so i use `node cli.js` for launch the CLI where from i put the date like email,username,password ecc..
When the server take the request from the user, it throw me this error:

[image]

this is a part of server's code(app.js):

`var users = require('./users.json');`

```
{console.log(req.body);
if(req.body.new_password === req.body.new_password_confirm && req.body.new_email === req.body.new_email_confirm ){

    let user = users.find((item )=>{ //<---- the method "find" who generate error
        return item.username === req.body.new_username || item.email === req.body.new_email;
    });
    
    if(!!user){
        res.send("email o username già in uso");
    }else 
    if(!!user == false){
        res.status(200).send("utente aggiunto");
        let user_json = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        fs.writeFileSync('users.json', user_json);
    }
}else
res.status(200).send("email o password errati");
});`
```

and this is a part of client's code (cli.js):

```
 axios
  .post("http://localhost:8080/", answers)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.data) {
      var registration_data = [
        {
          type: "input",
          name: "new_email",
          message: "email:",
        },
        {
          type: "input",
          name: "new_email_confirm",
          message: "confirm email:",
        },
        {
          type: "input",
          name: "new_username",
          message: "username:",
        },
        {
          type: "password",
          name: "new_password",
          message: "password:",
          mask: "*",
        },
        {
          type: "password",
          name: "new_password_confirm",
          message: "confirm password:",
          mask: "*",
        },
      ];

      inquirer.prompt(registration_data).then(async (answers) => {
        console.log("\nTrying Validation... ");

        axios
          .post("http://localhost:8080/new_user", answers)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
          });
      });
    } else if (!response.data) {
      console.log("TODO: LOGIN");
    }
  })
  .catch((response) => {
    console.error(response);
  });
```

IDK why the error say `.find` is not a function when actually it is.

Comment: On the line before you access the `users`, why not log it and see if it contains what you think it contains

Comment: Presuming `users` is JSON, it can't contain any functions.

Comment: Caching issue? https://goenning.net/2016/04/14/stop-reading-json-files-with-require/

Comment: `.find` is a valid function if the JSON contains an array

Comment: No `JSON` would not work if it's not parsed into a valid JS object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after some try i'have solved that.

i' m an idiot and i'm sorry.

look what was inside to user.json:

```
{
    "new_email": "",
    "new_email_confirm": "",
    "new_username": "",
    "new_password": "",
    "new_password_confirm": ""
  }
```

yes, exactly none a square brackets, user.json was an object not an array.

now that json file look like that:

```
[
  {
    "new_email": "",
    "new_email_confirm": "",
    "new_username": "",
    "new_password": "",
    "new_password_confirm": ""
  }
]
```

so, for the next time i'll remember, `.find`  can take only array not object.
thanks you all for your support

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not parsing the JSON in JS.

Try adding this at the beginning:

```
const users = require('./users.json');
const jsUsers = JSON.parse(users);
```

Then use `jsUsers` instead of users in your snippet.

This should help you to use `find`.

Bye!

Comment: i added those 2 codes lines but the only difference is the error on output:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous>`

Comment: What’s the new output?